# Trouble viewing Azure DocumentDB DocumentClient traffic in fiddler

Tags: azure, fiddler, azure-cosmosdb

I'm having trouble viewing viewing the communications from the Azure DocumentDB .NET SDK DocumentClient in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Edit: Specifically, I don't see traffic when i'm querying for documents. I see document creation POSTs.

I have no filters operating in fiddler and this is my code to create the client:

```
         var endpointUri = new Uri(Settings.Default.Endpoint);
        _client = new DocumentClient(endpointUri, Settings.Default.AuthKey, new ConnectionPolicy
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
            ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Https
        });
```

I've explicitly set the connection policy although I think the default is gateway.

Any ideas or insights?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Are you iterating through the results in the query? By nature, LINQ IQueryables use deferred execution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx.

Another possibility is that if you're looking specifically for a POST in your fiddler trace, note that in one specific case (a query with no filters), the query will be executed as a GET operation instead of a POST.

If you could post the code, we might be to help further.